# Nginx change header depending on upstream server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have nginx proxy and 2 upstreams(main upstream server and backup upstream server) servers in my environment, the goal is to change "proxy_set_header Host X/Y" depending on which upstream was chosen.

Right now I have only one idea to create another nginx instance and send all requests from my proxy to this instance, rewrite header and sent request further.

Does anyone know a more convenient solution?

Here is my simplified config:

```
http {
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

upstream images {
   server backend.test.com:8080 ;
   server backend-backup.test.com:8090 backup;
 }

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  images-test.test.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
 
    add_header                          Last-Modified "";
    add_header                          Pragma "public";
    add_header                          Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {}

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {}


    location / {
  # some not related to the question lines deleted
          proxy_set_header Host "backend.test.com";
          proxy_pass http://images;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using a map?

Comment: nope, i don't quite understand how use it in my situation with upstreams

Comment: If you add your current configuration to your question, I'll try to provide an answer.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I added my config, thanks in advance